# Building curl in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, libcurl, mingw-w64

i have a strange problem with eclipse.

My problem is when i download **LibCurl** and extract it to Local Disc C: i go to p**roject->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->MinGW C++ Linker->Miscellaneous->Other Objects->Add**. And i select to add **libcurl.a**

Afther that i go and add include path too and in **.cpp** file i add #**include "curl/curl.h"**. Then i compile a project and its all okay. Then i add some **cUrl** code:

```
      CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;
      curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

And when i compile a project again i get this error: ***undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'***

Here is my build command: `-c -fmessage-length=0 -static -libwsock32 -lws2_32 -g -Wall -Werror -lcurlpp -lcurl -L"c:\libcurl\lib"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, i fixed this problem by installing: eclipse, minGW32 on window XP and now libcUrl works perfect!